# Rails: How to use a rails app_config variable, as a feature-flag, to set conditional features in models and controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to set a feature flag "feature_enabled" in my rails application's app_config.yml.  In production the flag is false, and in staging it is true.  Is the best method to enable a feature in my model and controller, to access the feature_enabled flag in my config file and use it as a conditional (see below)?

### app_config.yml

```
staging:  &staging
<<: *defaults
feature_enabled: true

production:
<<: *staging
feature_enabled: false
```

### model_controller.rb:

```
def create
   if Rails.application.config.feature_enabled 
      #feature code
   end
end
```

### model.rb:

```
class modelName < ApplicationRecord
   if Rails.application.config.feature_enabled 
        after_save :feature_method
        validates_presence_of :feature_attribute
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't hurt to have your wrapper, so you can change how the feature flag is implemented without going all around your code

```
module Features
  include Singleton

  def foo_enabled?
    Rails.application.config.foo_enabled
  end

  def bar_enabled?
    Date.today.year == 2022
  end

  def bax_enabled?
    # do not use in class scope
    redis.get("mykey")
  end

  private

  def redis
    @redis ||= Redis.new(...)
  end
end

class ModelName < ApplicationRecord
  if Features.instance.foo_enabled?
    ...
  end
end
```